# How to automate interactive console applications in Python?

Tags: python, linux, shell, subprocess, linphone

I want to control running process/program by script in Python. 
I have a program `linphonec´ (You can install: apt-get install linphonec).
My task is:

1. Run `linphonec` (I'm using subprocess at the moment)
2. When `linphonec` is running it has many commands to control this and I want to e.g use `proxy list` (command in `linphonec`).

Simple flow:

```
test@ubuntu$ > linphonec
linphonec > proxy list
```

How can I do this?

Comment: look for pexpect module

Comment: try man linphonec or linphonec --help

Comment: I changed the title to address clearer the question. I re-formatted your text a little bit so it gets easier to read.

Comment: Ok, you're right. It's easier to read after your re-formatted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually 2 ways to communicate:

Run your program with `myprogram.py | linphonec` to pass everything you `print` to linphonec

Use [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) with [subprocess.PIPE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE) in constructor via keywrod-args for stdin (propably stdout and stderr, too) and then [communicate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) for a single command or use [stdin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdin) and [stdout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdout) ([stderr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stderr)) as files

```
import subprocess
p=subprocess.Popen("linphonec",
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    universal_newlines=True) #this is for text communication
p.stdin.write("proxy list\n")
result_first_line=p.stdout.readline()
```

Comment: Thank you! I tested your first notice and pexpect module.